# c++ Calculator Program - Finding the Factorial

Tags: c++, calculator, factorial

I cannot find where I have went wrong. The calculator works fine but when I want to find the factorial of a given number ('!' is used as the operator) i get strange answers like "1" and "59". Can someone find where i have slipped up and help? Also, sorry for the length of code I am about to upload.

```
#include "Header.h"

class Token {
public:
char kind;        // what kind of token
double value;     // for numbers: a value 
Token(char ch)    // make a Token from a char
    :kind(ch), value(0) { }    
Token(char ch, double val)     // make a Token from a char and a double
    :kind(ch), value(val) { }
};


class Token_stream {
public: 
Token_stream();   // make a Token_stream that reads from cin
Token get();      // get a Token (get() is defined elsewhere)
void putback(Token t);    // put a Token back
private:      
bool full;  
Token buffer;     // here is where we keep a Token put back using putback()
};


// The constructor just sets full to indicate that the buffer is empty:
Token_stream::Token_stream()
:full(false), buffer(0)    // no Token in buffer
{
}


// The putback() member function puts its argument back into the Token_stream's buffer:
void Token_stream::putback(Token t)
{
if (full) error("putback() into a full buffer");
buffer = t;       // copy t to buffer
full = true;      // buffer is now full
}


Token Token_stream::get()
{
if (full) {       // do we already have a Token ready?
    // remove token from buffer
    full=false;
    return buffer;
} 

char ch;
cin >> ch;    // note that >> skips whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.)

switch (ch) {
case ';':    // for "print"
case 'q':    // for "quit"
case '(': case ')': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/': case '{': case '}': case         '!':
    return Token(ch);        // let each character represent itself
case '.':
case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
    {    
        cin.putback(ch);         // put digit back into the input stream
        double val;
        cin >> val;              // read a floating-point number
        return Token('8',val);   // let '8' represent "a number"
    }
default:
    error("Bad token");
}
}


Token_stream ts;        // provides get() and putback() 



double expression();  // declaration so that primary() can call expression()


int factorial (int x)
{
int left = 1;
    for (int a = 1; a<=x;++a){
        left =a*left;
    }
        return left;
}

// deal with numbers and parentheses
double primary()
{
Token t = ts.get();
switch (t.kind) {
case '(':    // handle '(' expression ')'
    {    
        double d = expression();
        t = ts.get();
        if (t.kind != ')') error("')' expected)");
        return d;
    }
case '{':
    {
        double d = expression();
        t = ts.get();
        if (t.kind != '}') error ("'}' expected)");
        return d;
    }

case '8':
    return t.value;
default:
    return t.kind;
    error("primary expected");
}
}


// deal with *, /, and %
double term()
{
double left = primary();
Token t = ts.get();        // get the next token from token stream

while(true) {
    switch (t.kind) {
    case '*':
        left *= primary();
        t = ts.get();
        break;
    case '/':
        {    
            double d = primary();
            if (d == 0) error("divide by zero");
            left /= d; 
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        }
    case '!': 
        {
    Token t = ts.get();
    int d = factorial(t.value);
    return d;
        }

    default: 
        ts.putback(t);     // put t back into the token stream
        return left;
}
}
}


// deal with + and -
double expression()
{
double left = term();      // read and evaluate a Term
Token t = ts.get();        // get the next token from token stream

while(true) {    
    switch(t.kind) {
    case '+':
        left += term();    // evaluate Term and add
        t = ts.get();
        break;
    case '-':
        left -= term();    // evaluate Term and subtract
        t = ts.get();
        break;
    default: 
        ts.putback(t);     // put t back into the token stream
        return left;       // finally: no more + or -: return the answer
    }
}
}




int main()
try
{
while (cin) {
    double val = expression();
    Token t = ts.get();

    switch(t.kind){
case 'q': cout<<"end of programme";
    break;
case ';':        // ';' for "print now"
        cout << "=" << val << '\n';
        break;
default:
        ts.putback(t);
    val = expression();
    }
}
keep_window_open();
}
catch (exception& e) {
cerr << "error: " << e.what() << '\n'; 
keep_window_open();
return 1;
}
catch (...) {
cerr << "Oops: unknown exception!\n"; 
keep_window_open();
return 2;
}
```

Comment: Did you try if the right value comes out when you call the factorial function by hand? Did you try if the factorial function gets called with the right value when you enter it?

Comment: Can you remove unrelated parts of your code? **What have you already tried to solve this problem?** What worked and what didn't? Do you have any idea *why* your solutions didn't work?

Comment: You should spend a bit more time on formatting so that all code is indented properly, and I would also suggest getting rid of back-to-back blank lines. *Readable* code is more likely to get positive responses.

Comment: Exactly what are you feeding in for your factorial calculation? factorials grow VERY quickly, and a 32bit signed `int` isn't going to hold much.

Comment: the factorial hasn't to be done for larger than the number 8 anyway. yet still, when i type in !8 i get the wrong answer. i've tried the function on it's own and it works fine.

the core parts are:  
    case '!': 
        {
    Token t = ts.get();
    int d = factorial(t.value);
    return d;
        }

and

    int factorial (int x)
{
int left = 1;
    for (int a = 1; a<=x;++a){
        left =a*left;
    }
        return left;
}

Answer (score 1):

`int factorial (int x)` is fine algorithmically.

**But**, anything larger than `12!` will overflow your integer if it's a 32 bit signed. Using `uint64_t` will give you more numbers (up to `19!`) , but you ought to check the value of `x` in advance.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, you are getting strange results because of integer overflow.  Anything greater than or equal to `13!` is going to overflow a 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You are overflowing the max size of a 32 bit int. Try this...

```
 std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

with the

```
#incldue <limits>
```

library. Any int > what prints will have unknowable results.